# Is there a full list of potential labels that Google's Vision API will return?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-vision

I've been testing out Google's Vision API to attach labels to different images.

For a given image, I'll get back something like this:

```
"google_labels": {
            "responses": [{
                "labelAnnotations": [{
                    "score": 0.8966763,
                    "description": "food",
                    "mid": "/m/02wbm"
                }, {
                    "score": 0.80512983,
                    "description": "produce",
                    "mid": "/m/036qh8"
                }, {
                    "score": 0.73635191,
                    "description": "juice",
                    "mid": "/m/01z1kdw"
                }, {
                    "score": 0.69849229,
                    "description": "meal",
                    "mid": "/m/0krfg"
                }, {
                    "score": 0.53875387,
                    "description": "fruit",
                    "mid": "/m/02xwb"
                }]
            }]
        }
```

--> My questions are:

1. Does anybody know if Google has published their full list of labels (`['produce', 'meal', ...]`) and where I could find that?
2. Are those labels structured in any way? - e.g. is it known that 'food' is a superset of 'produce', for example.

I'm guessing 'No' and 'No' as I haven't been able to find anything, but, maybe not. Thanks!

Comment: Hey have you managed to find an answer to this question? I'm interested in this as well.

Comment: I haven't. At the time I basically scoured the documentation and couldn't find any reference to such a list (same with some googling), so I'm fairly sure that there wasn't any officially available list at the time I looked into it (July 2016).

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: any updates in 2019? @HillarySanders

Comment: @HillarySanders did you manage to find the list of potential labels?

Comment: @HillarySanders, any update on this? Did you manage to find this list?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

While I can't verify the completeness of the database, the [Google Open Images](https://storage.googleapis.com/openimages/web/index.html) project has a list of around 20k classifications.

If you browse to the [download](https://storage.googleapis.com/openimages/web/download.html) page you are able to download the list with those descriptions as [CSV](https://storage.googleapis.com/openimages/v5/class-descriptions.csv).

I checked a few reference images within CloudVision and had the following results:

```
ID / CloudVision Classification / OpenImages Classification
1. 01ssh5 / Shoulder / Shoulder (Body Part)
2. 09cx8 / Finger / Finger
3. 068jd / Photograph / Photograph
4. 01k74n / Facial expression / Facial expression
5. 04hgtk / Head / Human Head
```

I was able to find all IDs with the same meaning in the CSV - so as a base list this should be sufficient. Be aware that you should always match by ID, not by classification, as there are a few slight changes.

If you find any IDs in CloudVision but not in the list, I'd be interested to know in the comments!

Answer (score 5):

There is an API to search them called **Google Knowledge Graph API**:

https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/reference/rest/v1/

They link it at the bottom of **Google Vision API Documentation**:

https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/labels

---

**Edit**: more info

Ok, mids starting with /g/ are google entities, mids starting with /m/ are Freebase identifiers, but google kgraph API doesn't returns them always.

This data is public and can be downloaded, but there are too many records in the database and Google haven't published which ones of them they use.

Example of MID returned in vision api and the record in Wikidata:

```
{
    desc: "institution",
    mid: "/m/01r28c",
    score: 72.29216694831848,
    confidence: 0,
    locations: [ ],
    properties: [ ]
},
```

https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q178706

---

The last freebase dump can be downloaded here:

https://developers.google.com/freebase/

Comment: Sorry, this is not a correct response. The keys returned by "detectLabels" doesn't exists in Knowledge Graph API, I'm going to search for more info and fix the response. The DOC says that this is the correct method...